# How to add a variable from one xarray to another xarray?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am new to xarray. I have two xarray objects. I would like to add the 'latitude' and 'longitude' variables from the bottom xarray to the top xarray. I tried to concatenate by dimension (specifically the 'station_id' dimension) using the `concat()` method but this does not work. I think `merge()` is the way to go, but I am not sure how to do this. The arguments that go into `merge()` are going over my head (even after reading the documentation). I think this should be a simple process; I'm certain I'm missing something obvious.

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:       (station_id: 1218, time: 1509)
Coordinates:
  * time          (time) datetime64[ns] 1895-07-01 1895-08-01 ... 2021-03-01
  * station_id    (station_id) object 'USH00011084' ... 'USH00489905'
Data variables:
    tmax_mth_fls  (time, station_id) float64 33.21 31.74 31.84 ... 11.37 6.42
    tmin_mth_fls  (time, station_id) float64 22.28 21.24 19.58 ... -4.99 -7.13




<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:       (station_id: 1218)
Coordinates:
  * station_id    (station_id) object 'USH00011084' ... 'USH00489905'
Data variables:
    latitude      (station_id) float64 31.06 30.55 32.83 ... 42.11 44.01 44.98
    longitude     (station_id) float64 -87.05 -87.88 -88.13 ... -108.0 -110.7
    elevation     (station_id) float64 25.9 7.0 38.1 ... 1.238e+03 1.899e+03
    state         (station_id) object 'AL' 'AL' 'AL' 'AL' ... 'WY' 'WY' 'WY'
    station_name  (station_id) object 'BREWTON 3 SSE' ... 'YELLOWSTONE PK MAM...
    provider      (station_id) object 'USHCN' 'USHCN' ... 'USHCN' 'USHCN'
    sub_provider  (station_id) object '' '' '' '' '' '' '' ... '' '' '' '' '' ''
```

Comment: does `ds1['latitude'] = ds2['latitude']` do the trick? also, see [`da.assign_coords`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.assign_coords.html)

Comment: It was THAT easy? That worked! Thank you!